# InputAction with two binds does not trigger when the binds are used simultaneously

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

In the new Input System an InputAction with two bindings does not trigger when they are both used. Pressing the second bind while the first one is still active will not result in a pressed event being triggered. The first bind will subsequently not trigger any released event, resulting in a "stuck" behavior until the key is pressed again.

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375710/new-input-system-context-started-for-any-binding-in-an-action) asked the same question and made a graph that shows the problem, but nobody replied to the thread.
All the input types yield the same result and there doesn't seem to be a setting that can change this behavior. Expected behavior would be to trigger the action on every change of the input.

Solving this will allow me to output which key has been pressed with the new input system. I would be happy to edit the Input System code itself if someone could direct me to where this is handled.